# Rails - prevent Firebug/Developer Tools hacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I open Chrome Developer Tools and insert a destroy link (easy to do when it's a RESTful app and you know the routes) then I can easily delete things from the database without authorisation. What is the best way to tackle this problem? Is it to wrap the contents of the controller action in a CanCanCan style authorisation check?

Thanks

Comment: Pull out the network cable from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Authentication

For example, gem `devise` provides [helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) to check authentication in the controller (or you can do it with you own solution). It helps you to avoid requests from non-logged users.

2. Authorization

[CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) - good solutions to set rules for actions that allowed for a users. You can control access to different resources based on rules and actions with this resources.

CanCanCan example

```
def delete
  @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])

  #authorize user to have an ability delete this post
  #this will raise a CanCan::AccessDenied exception if not allowed
  authorize! :destroy, @post 

  ... your destroy logic
end
```

Read more about authorizing in controller on [CanCanCan wiki page](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions)

Comment: Thanks for your answer idej but I was actually looking more for an answer about the actual implementation. You mention using an authorization gem but what code should I actually use? Should I put the destroy/update action code inside of a CanCanCan `if can? :manage` method? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @DannySantos I added useful link and example in answer

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks idej! I dug a little further into the docs and found the `load_and_authorize_resource` method, which applies your solution to every action.

Comment: @DannySantos yeah, if you need it

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple actually. In your posts controller for example. You create before_actions:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def correct_user
    @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
    unless current_user?(@post.user)
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    end
  end

  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in"
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see. When you try to delete a post, the before_action kicks in and checks if the user is logged. Then it checks if the current_user owns the post. Only if both conditions are true, it will let the user delete the post else it will redirect the user. In the same way you handle other actions that require authorization like Admin panels, destroy users, update posts, etc.

As for the authorization itself, you can either implement it yourself using bcrypt or use a gem designed for that like Devise:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

All the installation instructions can be found on their github page.